# if (isset($_SESSION["Username"]) trouble

Tags: php

I'm making an admin page .. I need to make this page accessible to only a certain user which worked! and then I tried to make it not accessible by any user that not logged in so I used -

```
    if (isset($_SESSION["Username"]) && !isset($_POST["LOGIN"]))
    if($_SESSION["Username"] == "sara")
```

on each if statement there's a message that will appear .. if the user didn't login in the first place and if he wasn't the admin but somehow the first message appears even when the admin access it .. it lets it access the page and it shows the form but the message still appears at the bottom of the page .. and my code is a mess I've been trying for two days already ! can anyone help me please ? I tried to add another else but I get an error .. here's the full code -

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'header.php';
if (isset($_SESSION["Username"]) && !isset($_POST["LOGIN"])) {
  if($_SESSION["Username"] == "sara") {
    $conn = new mysqli($database_host, $database_login, $database_pass, $database_name);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
      $sql = "SELECT `cat_id` , `cat_name` FROM categorys";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
      if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        switch($_POST['Submit']) {
          case 'Submit2': 
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
              die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } else {
              $Thecategory  =  $_POST["Thecategory"];
              $q="INSERT INTO categorys( cat_name) VALUES ('$Thecategory')";
              if (mysqli_query($conn, $q)) {
                echo "New record created successfully 2222";
              } else {
                echo "Error: " . $q. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
              }
            }
            break;
          case 'Submit1':
            $Levelid = $_POST["Levelid"];
            $Levelserial = $_POST["Levelserial"];
            $word = $_POST["word"];
            $Thecategoryid  =  $_POST["taskOption"];
            $picfile = $_POST["picfile"];
            $fullword = $_POST["fullword"];
            $spelledword= $_POST["spelledword"];

            $sql="INSERT INTO questions( level_id, level_serial, q_word,q_cat_id , pic_file, word_file, s_word_file)
              VALUES ('$Levelid','$Levelserial',  '$word','$Thecategoryid ','$picfile' ,'$fullword','$spelledword')";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { 
              echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
              echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
            break;
        }
      } else {
        echo "
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <form>
        //form
          </form >

        <form  method=\"post\">

          <label >Level id :</label>
        <br>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"Levelid\" ><br>
          <label >  Level serial:</label>
          <br>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"Levelserial\" ><br>
          <label > The word is:</label>
        <br>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"word\" ><br>
          <label >The pic file is:</label>
          <br>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"picfile\" v><br>
          <label > The full word  file :</label> 
          <br>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"fullword\" ><br>
           <label >The spelled word file  :</label> 
        <br>
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"spelledword\" ><br>

         ";

        echo"
        <div >
        <label for=\"The category \">The category </label></br>
        <select name=\"taskOption\">

        ";

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?>
            </option> <?php } ?>
          </select> 
        <?php } ?>        
        <br><br>
        <?php
        echo"
          <input type=\"Submit\" value=\"Submit1\" name=\"Submit\">

        </form>

        </div>

        </body>
        </html>


        ";
      }
    }
  }

  echo "
    <head>
    <title>Relogin Please </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <br/> <br/>
    <div id=\"content1\">
      <div id=\"relog\">
      <h2 style=\" color:black ; font-size: 25px;\">you're not admin </h2>
    <a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"PIC/NIE7J6OOT.PNG\" ></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/> <br/>
    </center>
    </body>

    ";
} else {
  echo "
  <head>
  <title>Relogin Please </title>
      </head>
  <body>
  <center>
  <br/> <br/>
  <div id=\"content1\">
    <div id=\"relog\">
    <h2 style=\" color:black ; font-size: 25px;\">youare not admin </h2>
    <a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"PIC/NIE7J6OOT.PNG\"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
      <br/> <br/>
  </center>
  </body>
  ";
}
?>

<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

i need to place an else statement but i don't know where ! can anybody help with that please !

Comment: Have you tried printing out `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, true) . '</pre>'` and `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>'` to see what they actually contain?

Comment: @h2ooooooo no .. sir the sessions are good .. i access it when it's sara and i don't when it's not .. but the message keeps appearing even after i login with sara, it shows the form and the message .. i need to hide the message when i login with sara

Comment: Could you already fix it or do you have still problems? What do you mean with **...but somehow the first message appears even when the admin access it...**. Which _message_?

Answer (score 0):

This code is no longer safe:

if mypage.php contains this code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['Username']=='sara';
echo "<a href='http://the.link-to-your-admin_page.php' target='_blank'>link</a>";
```

If the link is clicked, the session admin as 1 will be carried to your page and the edit button will be appeared.

safest way is to set a token (this is a very simple step) right after login. 
e.g `$token = md5(uniqidsession(rsand(), true)); $_SESSION['token']=$token;`

on top of every page put something like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){ die('Access Denied');}
if(!isset($_SESSION['Username'])){ die('Access Granted');}
```

first check the token carry in the SESSION and then Check the user ID, including level of permissions for users. However, only you know sara as the admin, this is a just in case precaution. This is just a simple approach, put more fingerprint scan code at the beginning to make it complex to intercept sessionid.